# "aws-sdk" error ,My Node js Project works fine when run in windows , but wont work in linux enviornment

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk

It works fine in windows but gives error in linux ec2 instance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Linux is case sensitive whereas windows is not.
make sure that the path is properly cased

In this case:

```
aws-sdk/clients/S3
```

should be

```
aws-sdk/clients/s3
```

**s3** should be in lower case.